# in_array() won't work when checking if numeric indexed array is in associative array

Tags: php, arrays

Can somebody explain why `in_array()` is returning false for the following example:

```
$arrA=array('apple');
$arrB=array(
          'first'=>'banana',
          'second'=>'apple'
          );
var_dump(in_array($arrA,$arrB)); // false
```

On a related note: If `$arrA` had more than one element, how would I check if **any/at least one** value of `$arrA` is in `$arrB` ?

Thank you!

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?  Searching for an array within an array wasn't added until version 4.2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`in_array($item, $array)` tests whether `$item` is one of the values in `$array`. The values in `$arrB` are strings, but `$arrA` is a whole array. An array is not the same thing as a string, even if the array just contains a single element that's a string. You could use:

```
in_array($arrA[0], $arrB) // true
```

If you want to test whether the two arrays have any elements in common, use:

```
count(array_intersect($arrA, $arrB)) > 0
```

Comment: [The documentation](http://us1.php.net/in_array) for `in_arary()` states that `needle` can be an array.

Comment: I never said it couldn't be. But then it searches for that array in the haystack. It's useful when the haystack is a 2-dimensional array.

Comment: See example #3 in the documentation you linked to.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying - the documentation is quite confusing at this point!

Answer (score 1):

You search for array, not string:

```
$arrA=array('apple');
$arrB=array(
          'first'=>'banana',
          'second'=>'apple'
          );
var_dump(in_array($arrA,$arrB)); // false
var_dump(in_array('apple',$arrB)); // true
```

Comment: nice simp;e answer +1 and for testing presence of any element common?

Answer (score 1):

Some of these other answers seem to have [skimped on the documentation](https://www.php.net/in_array#refsect1-function.in-array-changelog), specifically this note:

```
 Changelog  
 Version    Description  
 4.2.0      needle may now be an array.
```

The issue is that when you're searching for an array within an array, you're not looking for *each item* in needle, you're looking for needle *as a whole*.

In your case, `$arrA` is `array('apple')`, so `in_array` looks for `array('apple')` within `$arrB`.
The reason the return value is `false` is because `array('apple')` *isn't* in `$arrB` as a whole even though the contents are.

This example should help clear things up a bit:

```
$arrA = array('apple');

$arrB = array(
          'first' => 'banana',
          'second'=> 'apple'
          );
          
$arrC = array(
          'first' => 'banana',
          'second'=> array('apple')
          );

var_dump(in_array($arrA, $arrB)); // false
var_dump(in_array($arrA, $arrC)); // true
```

If you're looking to see which items in `$arrA` exist in `$arrB`, then you should use [array_intersect](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php).

Comment: Thanks! The statement that 'needle may be an array' in the docs let me believe I could check for the existence of the values of the needle array. But obviously, I can't. array_intersect() is the way to go

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of the `in_array` function is to determine if a single value (the 'needle') exists within an array (the `haystack`).

What you seem to want to do is find where one or more values from one array exist within another. This is known as intersection, and can be done in PHP using `array_intersect`. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php

Answer (score 0):

`in_array` first param `needle` type is `mixed`.

You can do it like this:

```
var_dump(in_array('apple', array_values($arrB))); // true
// or
var_dump(in_array('apple', $arrB)); // true
```

If you want to check multiple items, you can make a helper function like this:

```
$arrB=array(
          'first'=>'banana',
          'second'=>'apple'
          );

function checkInArray($toCheck, $sourceArray) {
    $totalIn = 0;
    foreach ($toCheck as $k => $v) {
        if (in_array($v, $sourceArray))
            $totalIn++;
    }
    return ($totalIn == sizeof($toCheck));
}

var_dump(checkInArray(array('apple','banana'), $arrB)); // true
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `array_intersect()` can do you work

```
$arrA=array('apple');
$arrB=array(
      'first'=>'banana',
      'second'=>'apple'
      );
if(array_intersect($arrA, $arrB))
echo"yes exist";
```

read more about [array_intersect](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php)

Answer (score 0):

in_array checks for exact array match match

```
$arrA=array('apple');
$arrB=array(
    'first'=>'banana',
    'second'=>'apple'
);
$arrC=array(
    'first'=>array('banana'),
    'second'=>array('apple')
);
echo var_export(in_array($arrA,$arrB),true) . "<br/>\n"; // false
echo var_export(in_array($arrA[0],$arrB),true) . "<br/>\n"; // true
echo var_export(in_array($arrA,$arrC),true) . "<br/>\n"; // true
```